# VBA Round function vs Worksheet Round function

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to change this Excel function into VBA code

Excel

```
=ROUND(value,sigfig-(1+INT(LOG10(ABS(value)))))
```

VBA

```
Public Function sigfig(val As Double, sigf As Integer) As Double
Dim var As Double
var = Abs(val)
var = Application.WorksheetFunction.Log10(var)
var = Int(var)
sigf = sigf - (1 + var)
sigfig = Round(val, sigf)
End Function
```

For below 0, both of the Excel and VBA work well. However in VBA, when value (val) is more than sigfig (sigf), it gives me an error. For example, if I want to have 3 sigfig of 55481, it gives #VALUE, instead of 55500.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the second argument in VBA's `Round` function can't be negative, but in the worksheet function's version it can.

The solution is simple, just use:

```
sigfig = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(val, sigf)
```

and it will work as intended.

It is significant that Application.WorksheetFunction makes `Round` available. It does that precisely because the VBA function does not duplicate its functionality exactly. By contrast, `Abs` would just duplicate the functionality, so you can't call the worksheet version of that function from VBA.

Comment: ... and also `Round` is banker's rounding... so pretty much steer clear, yeah.