# Average with a significant figure

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to take an average of data range with a desired significant figure. But it returns 0. What could possibly be wrong?

```
Public Function avg(rng As Range, sigf As Integer) As Double

Dim var As Double

var = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng)
var = Application.WorksheetFunction.Log10(Abs(var))
var = Int(var)
sigf = sigf - (1 + var)

avg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(var, sigf)

End Function
```

Comment: The re-use of `var` in `var = Application.WorksheetFunction.Log10(Abs(var))` seems suspect - you're overwriting the result from the previous line.

Comment: Try running the code line by line (pressing F8 being in VBE) and see what each line returns...

Comment: please provide some data you are using as an example..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61759694/vba-round-function-vs-worksheet-round-function